# How to set daily update limit for django model(db)?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, export-to-excel, django-import-export

Hi I'm having one Django web app where My model A contains 1000 records and I want to set a daily update limit for example if users are updating that data by uploading a **.xls** file then it should count how many records updated and once it is more than 500 then the user should get an Error message(Is there Any easy way to implement this at file processing level).

Can Anyone help me how to implement this (Is there an SQLite parameter that I can mention in  settings.py)

below is my upload code. (Here I have tried to store the count value and comparing it with half of the record but again how to reset it after 12/certain time/hrs?)

```
def CTA_upload(request):
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            movie_resource = CTAResource()
    ##we will get data in movie_resources####
    dataset = Dataset()
    new_movie = request.FILES['file']
    if not new_movie.name.endswith('xls'):
        messages.info(request, 'Sorry Wrong File Format.Please Upload valid format')
    return render(request, 'apple/uploadinfosys.html')
    messages.info(request, 'Uploading Data Line by Line...')
    imported_data = dataset.load(new_movie.read(), format='xls')
    count = 1
    for data in imported_data:
        value = CTA(
            data[0],
            data[1],
            data[2],
            data[3],
            data[4],
            data[5],
            data[6],
            data[7],
            data[8],
        )
    count = count + 1
    value.save()
    # messages.info(request, count)
    # time.sleep(1)
    messages.info(request, 'File Uploaded Successfully...')

    except:
    messages.info(request,
                  'Same Email ID has been observed more than once.Except that other records has been added../nPlease Make sure Email field should be unique.')

    return render(request, 'app/cta.html')
```

Comment: does other answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66183459/39296